# Content script needs to be in the same folder as manifest.json

Tags: reactjs, webpack, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Whenever I compile my Chrome extension and try to reload it in Chrome, I get an error about the content script not being in the same folder as `manifest.json`. I have to do `mv dist/js/content.js* dist/` to fix this every time.

In `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./src/index.js",
        content: "./src/content.js"
    },
    etc.
```

In `manifest.json`:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<url pattern>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
]
```

How do I fix my configuration so that I don't have to move `content.js` after every re-compilation?

Comment: Simply add `js/` before content.js in `"js"` field.